# Is the way a bot submits a form different than someone using a browser?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form that uses php to send the info captured to me in an email.

Recently I have been recieving a number of these emails that do not have useful information. I assumed that this was just bots submitting random forms since I don't bother with a capture or anything else and dismissed it.

Today when one of these emails came in I noticed that there is no way that I could reproduce the contents of the emails I have been receiving if I submitted my form from a browser because there are several fields that would contain something - even if it's just the default value which my drop down menus have.

Do you think that the way the bots (if that is what is doing this) are submitting the form removing the default values? Or would it be more likely that these could be legitimate users and my php code has a bug and is somehow breaking my email form?

My php code basically loops through and checks if fields are empty and if they are not it adds it to the email body.

edit:

Here's the php code I use:

```
 $valid = new Validation($_POST);
if($CONTINUE = $valid->success) {
    $to = "myemail";
    $subject = "Subject";
    $from_email = $to;
    $from_name = $name;
    $headers = "From: $from_name<$from_email>\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: <$email>\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: <$from_email>\n"; 



    $body = "The following information we recently submitted\n";

    $qstring="";

    unset($_POST['required_fields']);
    reset($_POST);
    while(list($key, $value) = each($_POST)) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $body .= proper_form($key) . ":  " . stripslashes($value) ."\n";
            $qstring .= "&".$key."=".$value;
        }   
    }

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: Use [captcher](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: Can you post the email code you use?

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't tell if you've done anything wrong.

Comment: To answer your question in the title, the bots could be posting directly to your email script and bypassing your form, yes.

Comment: you've got `"required_fields"` coming into the program via `$_POST`, which means that yes, it is easy for a bot or a hacker to bypass it entirely. Don't trust anything that the user submits on the form.

Comment: Does this make my server vunerable for a spammer to use to send spam?

Answer (score 2):

Most forms are submitted using HTTP, using a `POST` request. These requests merely have data packaged in them - HTTP doesn't care about valid values in dropdowns. The average browser does, however. When the request is submitted by a browser, it plays by the rules of the HTML form in question. If I were to manually submit a `POST` (using `curl`, or a bot), I could put in any data I wanted.

You could fix this by:

1. only looping over `$_POST` parameters you know your form can submit
2. validating those parameters' values in your PHP.

(By the way, a captcha is probably a reasonable idea. Just try to get one that isn't too hard to read - I've run into several ridiculously hard captchas in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know whatever bot (probably a crawler) is including additional parameters in the call, you can probably assume it is not a directed attack on your server, though it could be fishing for weaknesses in your mysql escaping (or similar attacks).

A few things I'd focus on:

1) POST the page content (instead of GET) to avoid random web links if your domain was previously owned by someone else.

2) If the $_POST contains anything other than the fields you expect, ignore that entire post (browser will not send additional fields unless you specified them yourself or someone added them to the page with a greasemonkey script (or similar)).
You can check this with something like:

```
$allowedParams = array('name', 'email', 'subject', 'etc');
foreach($_POST as $param=>$val) {
    if(!in_array($param, $allowedParams))
    {
       die();
    }
}
```

3) Check the referer and/or useragent for common bots and either deny the data or handle it differently. Not bulletproof, but handy.

4) If this script is being called via Ajax, look into [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

5) [Don't use a captcha](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/07/02/why-you-should-never-use-a-captcha/) unless you really really really have to (you probably don't). If you do decide on a captcha, use something simple like a "Are you human? (type yes)" with a textbox for "yes". Not one of those crazy, read this mess captchas.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bob.

I don't think I can be sure that the bot/crawler is including additional parameters because when I get the emails they are blank except for 3 fields which have default values. The form contains 6 fields with default values, so I was confused that only 3 kept coming in the emails when there is no way I could reproduce that with a browser and I would have thought that a bot would be all or nothing not 1/2 the fields. 

I'll look into the your other suggestions for 1 & 2.

For #3, is there a list you know of which contains useragents of common bots I can reference?

Comment: Both blacklisting and whitelisting useragents (though it's safe to assume all browsers will have a useragent, some bots will not) have their own problems, I'd just catch the useragent of every form submission then look for commonalities in the ones sending the junk data, then block that commonality.